# Windows 10 bootable USB drive when install.wim >4GiB

Tags: windows-10, usb-flash-drive, bootable-media

Starting from a Windows 10 ISO image file with >4GiB `install.wim` (including current `Win10_1809Oct_<language>_x64.iso` of like 4.8GiB built 2018/10/30), how can I make a USB drive that is bootable including on a non-UEFI machine?

[MediaCreationTool1809.exe](https://software-download.microsoft.com/download/pr/MediaCreationTool1809.exe) works, but it downloads everything, and modifies at least 3 files: `install.esd` replacing `install.wim`, `boot.wim`, and `ws.dat`. These changes remove some editions of Windows (e.g. Pro Education and Pro for workstations, and their N variations), and make it impossible to check integrity of the modified files against a fixed hash.

Comment: I also suggestion to use media creation tool it is the most easy way, anyway on the steps you mention in your question it is missing only one step, the installation of the boot sector in to usb, mount the installation iso, navigate in to x:/boot (if x is the mounted iso drive letter) from a CMD, once you are inside that folder run this command: bootsect /nt60 f: (where f: is the device letter of your USB.

Comment: @AtomiX84: ah I tried `BOOTSECT /NT60 F: /MBR` on top of my recipe, and that worked! Thanks.

Comment: Greate! I was forget the /mbr flag, that useful to install boot sector for MBR disk :D

Comment: If you want to download the official Windows 10 ISO image, you can change your user-agent to be "Linux" and visit the Windows 10 download page ([source](https://tqdev.com/2016-windows-10-clean-install)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a method yielding a USB drive bootable both on a UEFI and non-UEFI machine. Basically

- We use FAT32 in order to be bootable under all UEFI system
- We split the large "install.wim" file as a workaround to the 4GiB file size limit

Under a working Windows 10:

1. Mount the ISO (e.g. Open with… Windows Explorer). In the following I'll assume it's assigned to drive `F:`. Adjust steps 4, 5 (twice), 6 as necessary.
2. Connect an 8GB to 32GB USB drive with no useful data
3. Open a command line prompt with elevate privileges (Windows key, type "cmd", right-click on the cmd icon on the top left, launch as administrator). Type the following commands
4. `if exist F:\sources\install.wim diskpart` (this checks the file "install.wim" is where it is expected in the ISO image, and if so launches DISKPART). Type the following  (lowercase letters are optional, case is not sensitive)

   - `LISt DISk`
   - `SELect DISk` *N* (replace *N* with appropriate number)
   - *!! Triple-check the disk number !!*
   - `CLEan` (occasional access error can typically be ignored)
   - `CREate PARtition PRImary`
   - `FORmat FS=FAT32 QUICK LABEL=WIN10`
   - `ASSign LETTER=X` (assuming this drive letter is unassigned; adjust steps 5 and 6 as necessary)
   - `ACTive` (this step is critical and why we use DISKPART)
   - `EXIt`
5. `robocopy F:\ X:\ /E /XF F:\sources\install.wim` (this copies all files from the mounted ISO to the USB disk, except "install.wim")
6. `Dism /Split-Image /ImageFile:F:\sources\install.wim /SWMFile:X:\sources\install.swm /FileSize:3840` (this copy "install.wim" split as two files "install.swm" and "install1.swm")
7. Close the command window
8. Eject the USB drive

Note: for a method that does not split the wim file, see this [former version of the present answer](https://superuser.com/revisions/1392252/6). Credits to this [other answer](https://superuser.com/a/1401895/221661) for the simplification. An advantage is that no file with a different hash/date is involved.

Answer (score 7):

If you're on Linux like Marco, the solution posted by JesuLovesMe can also be applied using wimtools instead of using Dism:

- Mount the ISO
- Create a FAT32 filesystem on the USB stick with mkfs.vfat and mount it
- Copy over all contents of the ISO to the USB stick except "sources/install.wim"
- Call wimsplit on install.wim like this:

  `wimsplit /path/to/ISO/sources/install.wim /path/to/USB/sources/install.swm 3000`

This will create install.swm and install2.swm on the stick, with a maximum size of 3000 MiB for each file. If the original install.wim exceeds 6000 MiB in a future release, this will still work and create an additional install3.swm.

For UEFI booting, that's all you need, for non-UEFI systems you need to install a bootloader as usual.

Also remember to make any customizations to install.wim before splitting it, as the split files *cannot be changed anymore*!

Answer (score 4):

For all the poor **Linux** admins without a Windows computer like me, who need to help relatives installing Windows 10 (sigh).
This is the way under Linux (in my case Ubuntu Bionic).

Use [UNetbootin](https://launchpad.net/%7Egezakovacs/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) to create an USB-Stick from the Windows ISO. Unfortunately there will be no message, that it truncated the install.wim (in case it is larger than 4G).
At least UNetbooin creates a bootable USB-Stick.

Now, use 7zip (`apt-get install p7zip`) to extract the ISO (it is enough to extract the install.wim file. Do not use the broken install.wim from the created USB-Stick !!). Or alternatively mount the Windows-ISO if you are a more advanced Linux user.

Next use wimexport (`apt-get install wimtools`) to extract and compress the Windows type needed from original install.wim. With `wiminfo` you can list all included Windows types.

In my case I ran (see `man wimexport`): `wimexport install.wim 1 home.wim --compress=LZX:100`

The previous step created a small (<4G) wim-file which I copied into the sources directory of the UNetbootin created USB-Stick overwriting the broken install.wim (e.g. `cp home.wim /mnt/sources/install.wim`).

With this I could successfully boot the Windows 10 installer and do the install.

Comment: The 4GB cap is due to UNetbootin creating the partition FAT32 instead of NTFS to handle larger files.  Here is an awesome script that formats the device, creates partitions, and copies the ISO files by specifying the install file and the USB device.  https://linuxconfig.org/creating-a-bootable-usb-for-windows-10-and-11-on-linux

Answer (score 2):

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/split-a-windows-image--wim--file-to-span-across-multiple-dvds

Someone stumbled upon this graceful solution by Microsoft.
This way, the FAT32 partitioned USB works with newer Laptops that has a different Boot Code too.

The Above is the solution I had been using for a long while too, until someone stumbled upon this. Thank you!!

Thanks!!

*Quote: `Dism /Split-Image /ImageFile:C:\sources\install.wim /SWMFile:C:\sources\install.swm /FileSize:3999`

Answer (score 1):

Although Marco has a very good answer for **Linux** users splitting the `install.wim` using `wimsplit` you may also recompress the file on Linux using `wimlib-imagex optimize` (also from the `wimtools` package) with the following command:

```
wimlib-imagex optimize install.wim --solid
```

It may take a long time, but the result will just be a smaller `install.wim` (<4GB).

Source: [TQdev.com](https://tqdev.com/2019-cannot-copy-windows-10-install-wim)

Answer (score 1):

to split a `install.esd` file, you must first convert it to `install.wim`

then use `wimsplit` to produce `install.swm` and `install2.swm`

```sh
mkdir mnt
sudo mount -o loop *.iso mnt

du -h mnt/sources/install* 
# 4.2G mnt/sources/install.esd

# 4G is maximum file size on FAT32
# -> split the file

cp -r mnt split
chmod -R +w split
rm split/sources/install.esd

wimsplit mnt/sources/install.esd split/sources/install.wim 4000 
# [ERROR] Splitting of WIM containing solid resources is not supported.
#         Export it in non-solid format first.

# convert to non-solid format per `man wimexport`
# compression level 1 -> 6GB install.wim
# i dont care about file size, just make it quick
wimexport mnt/sources/install.esd all tmp-install.wim --compress=LZX:1

# we must use *.swm file extension for split files
# with *.wim, install says "insert windows installation disc 2"
wimsplit tmp-install.wim split/sources/install.swm 4000 

du -h split/sources/install* 
# 2.0G split/sources/install2.swm
# 4.0G split/sources/install.swm

# create new iso
mkisofs -o split.iso split

# write iso
sudo woeusb --partition split.iso /dev/sdbTODO
```